# Core Data - FetchedResults<Item> has no member 'remove'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have some items in a list which I am adding swipe to delete functionality to. When using a delete function, I'm getting an error telling me that the `FetchedResults<tem>` object has no member 'remove'. What's happening?

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@FetchRequest(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors:[]) var items: FetchedResults<Item>

...

List {
    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { (item: Item) in
        Text(item.title ?? "New Item")
            .font(.headline)
}
    .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
}

func deleteItems(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    self.items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `delete` method on `managedObjectContext`. Also, don't forget to save once deletion is complete.

```
func deleteItems(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    for index in offsets {
        let item = items[index]
        moc.delete(item)
    }
    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {
        // handle the Core Data error
    }
}
```